# Can't track HTTP response code in middleware

Tags: http, go, server, wrapper, middleware

I'm using the `go-openapi` to generate from a swagger config an http server and handle all handlers.
The schema of my middleware would be `request -> override func -> do http stuff -> logs response code -> response`.

Here's my middleware:

```golang
func (pm *PrometheusMetrics) HTTPMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        start := time.Now()
        statusRecoder := &utils.StatusRecorder{ResponseWriter: w, StatusCode: 200}
        logrus.Infof("--> %v %v", r.Method, r.URL.Path)
        // statusRecoder := negroni.NewResponseWriter(w) <-- tried this solution, didn't worked

        h.ServeHTTP(statusRecoder, r)

        logrus.Infof("<-- %v", statusRecoder.Status()) // should display status code
        duration := time.Since(start)
        statusCode := strconv.Itoa(statusRecoder.Status())

        pm.PushHTTPMetrics(r.URL.Path, statusCode, duration.Seconds())
    })
}
```

And here's how I pass the middleware:

```golang
func setupGlobalMiddleware(handler http.Handler, promMetrics *apihandlers.PrometheusMetrics) http.Handler {
    middle := interpose.New()
    middle.UseHandler(handler)

    recoveryMiddleware := recovr.New()
    middle.Use(recoveryMiddleware)

    logrusMiddleware := interposeMiddleware.NegroniLogrus()
    middle.Use(logrusMiddleware)
    middle.Use(func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return promMetrics.HTTPMiddleware(h)
    })

    corsMiddleware := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedHeaders:     []string{"*"},
        AllowedOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        MaxAge:             1000,
        OptionsPassthrough: false,
    })
    if log.GetLevel() >= log.DebugLevel {
        corsMiddleware.Log = log.StandardLogger()
    }

    return corsMiddleware.Handler(middle)
}
```

And finally, where I call the `setupGlobalMiddleware` function:

```golang
func configureAPI(api *operations.KubeesAPI) http.Handler { // operations is package generated by go-openapi
    // Some setup...
    return setupGlobalMiddleware(api.Serve(setupMiddlewares), promMetrics)
}
```

The override of statusRecoder:

```golang
type StatusRecorder struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    StatusCode int
}

// WriteHeader is the fake function to record status code
func (rec *StatusRecorder) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    logrus.Infof("hello there: %v", statusCode)
    rec.StatusCode = statusCode
    rec.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}
```

As you can see, I'm overriding the `WriteHeader` function from the `http.Handler` to just store the status code and access it outside, then call the original `WriteHeader` function. The problem here, is that my function `WriteHeader` is never called. And can't figure out why it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was a little bit more complex to understand if you didn't have the entire package list.
The problem was the way that `go-openapi` and `go-swagger` implement middlewares in the code and handle them. Many other installed packages have this problem.
To make sure I retrieve properly the status code, I put the middleware at the rigth bottom of middlewares declaration.

Code:

```golang
func setupGlobalMiddleware(handler http.Handler, promMetrics *apihandlers.PrometheusMetrics) http.Handler {
    middle := interpose.New()
    middle.UseHandler(handler)

    recoveryMiddleware := recovr.New()
    middle.Use(recoveryMiddleware)

    logrusMiddleware := interposeMiddleware.NegroniLogrus()
    middle.Use(logrusMiddleware)

    // the old declaration was here

    corsMiddleware := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedHeaders:     []string{"*"},
        AllowedOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowedMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        MaxAge:             1000,
        OptionsPassthrough: false,
    })
    if log.GetLevel() >= log.DebugLevel {
        corsMiddleware.Log = log.StandardLogger()
    }

    // notice the changement where the promMetrics.HTTPMiddleware is now in the bottom
    return corsMiddleware.Handler(promMetrics.HTTPMiddleware(middle))
    // return corsMiddleware.Handler(middle) <-- old line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem here, is that my function WriteHeader is never called. And can't figure out why it's not.

Because Go uses composition, not inheretence.  `WriteHeader` is most frequently called automatically by the first call to `Write()`. From the [`http.ResponseWriter` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter):

> ```
> // Write writes the data to the connection as part of an HTTP reply.
> //
> // If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls
> // WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data. If the Header
> // does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set
> // to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to
> // DetectContentType. Additionally, if the total size of all written
> // data is under a few KB and there are no Flush calls, the
> // Content-Length header is added automatically.
> ```

But since you haven't defined your own `Write` method, the embedded one (provided by the embedded instance of `http.ResponseWriter`) is called instead. When that `Write()` method is called, and it then calls `WriteHeader`, it calls the original `WriteHeader` method, not your version.

The solution is to also provide your own `Write` method, which wraps the original, and calls your version of `WriteHeader` when needed.

```golang
type StatusRecorder struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    StatusCode int
    written bool
}

// WriteHeader is the fake function to record status code
func (rec *StatusRecorder) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    rec.written = true
    logrus.Infof("hello there: %v", statusCode)
    rec.StatusCode = statusCode
    rec.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}

func (rec *StatusRecorder) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {method
    if !rec.written {
        rec.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
    return rec.Write(p)
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, right. I've seen that but I didn't thought that would use the initial WriteHeader method :/. Gonna try this out.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't worked :/. It didn't even go into the Write method. I really thing one of my package (either go-openapi, interpose or even cors) is overriding this for its needs... But although, that didn't solved the problem, that would have caused issues for later :D. Thank you buddy !